# I need a way to remove non-german letters and only allow specific characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to gsub a String so that I have a string in the end which has

- only german letters and normal Numbers
- no special characters except `,`  `.` `?` and `!`
- no leading or trailing non-printable characters
- no consecutive non-printable characters, there should only be one space between words
- there should be no whitespace in front of the allowed special characters `.` `,` `?` `!`
- the `,` and `.` is not allowed to be the last character

Example (On two lines to be more visible for you):

```
'   §$%""%& Überschnell    du$§"rch   die Nacht .
    Genießen Sie Ihre Aussicht , Sie Blödm人物ann   !   $"§ '
```

Should become:

```
'Überschnell durch die Nacht. Genießen Sie Ihre Aussicht, Sie Blödmann!'
```

I hope it is clear what I need to the string to happen. Its for prettier titles in my Rails app when the user types anything that isnt English or german or doesnt care about right punctuation or so.

Edit: This is what works ok at the moment thanks to @mudasobwa

```
irb(main):021:0> str='   §$%""%& Überschnell    du$§"rch   die Nacht .   Genießen Sie Ihre Aussicht , Sie Blödm??an>
=> "   \xF5$%\"\"%& \x9Aberschnell    du$\xF5\"rch   die Nacht .   Genie\xE1en Sie Ihre Aussicht , Sie Bl\x94dm??ann   !   $\"\xF5 "

irb(main):016:0> str=str.gsub(/\s\s+/, ' ')
=> " \xF5$%\"\"%& \x9Aberschnell du$\xF5\"rch die Nacht . Genie\xE1en Sie Ihre Aussicht , Sie Bl\x94dm??ann ! $\"\xF5 "

irb(main):017:0> str=str.gsub(/[^a-zA-z\s!?.,äöüÄÄÖÜß]/, "")
=> "  \x9Aberschnell durch die Nacht . Genie\xE1en Sie Ihre Aussicht , Sie Bl\x94dm??ann !  "

irb(main):018:0> str=str.gsub(/\s+([,.!?])/, "\\1")
=> "  \x9Aberschnell durch die Nacht. Genie\xE1en Sie Ihre Aussicht, Sie Bl\x94dm??ann!  "

irb(main):019:0> str=str.strip
=> "\x9Aberschnell durch die Nacht. Genie\xE1en Sie Ihre Aussicht, Sie Bl\x94dm??ann!"

irb(main):020:0> str=str.encode("UTF-8").unicode_normalize(:nfc)
=> "Überschnell durch die Nacht. Genießen Sie Ihre Aussicht, Sie Blödm??ann!"
```

But when on Windows I get a `Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with CP850 string)`

Will this happen in the production app on HEroku also or can I just use this without worrying??

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: 3 Steps: ``gsub(/\s\s+/, ' ')``,  then ``gsub(/\A\W+/, '')`` and then ``gsub(/[^[a-zA-z\s!?äöüÄÄÖÜß]]/, "")``

Comment: Remove the inner square brackets: `gsub(/[^a-zA-z\s!?äöüÄÄÖÜß]/, "")`

Comment: It didnt change anything. The onyl thing that works is removing consecutive whitepsaces. The one step you are mentioning removes all characters I dont want but chinese ones stay as ??. For the last steps I need to remove whitespaces in fron of the special characters and leading and trailing whitepaces at the beginning and the end of the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here would be to **unicode normalize the input to `:nfc` form**:

```
'   §$%""%& Überschnell    du$§"rch   die Nacht . ' \
'Genießen Sie Ihre Aussicht , Sie Blödm人物ann   !   $"§ '.
  unicode_normalize(:nfc).  # ⇐ HERE
  gsub(/\s+([,.!?])/, "\\1").
  gsub(/[^a-zA-Z,.!?äöüÄÖÜß\s]/, "").
  strip.
  squeeze

#⇒ 'Überschnell durch die Nacht. Genießen Sie Ihre Aussicht, Sie Blödmann!'
```

Comment: I am working on windows and it uses CP850 so I am getting ``Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with CP850 string)``

Comment: Just tested it and all my tests are green with that thank you. And I didnt need to nromalize. The ``strip`` and the one with replacing spaces in front of special charachters is all I needed. Thank you for that again